# Deployment strategy for servers on internal network

Tags: 8, composer, deployment

I am following composer based workflow for Drupal 8, in which I commit only custom code and use `composer install` to install it on another environment.

However, on new workflow, the dev, test, staging instances are on Internal network, with no access to Internet (due to security reasons).

Can you suggest a deployment strategy to use in this scenario, so that I don't have to commit the whole files in git repository, as is.

**PS:** I am ok with something like Acquia pipelines, where things are 'compiled' into a branch, which is used for deployment. But using that is ruled out, as the code can't be sent to outside because of security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use Acquia BLT. It generates a deployment artifact, which can be deployed anywhere.

So that the composer will stay in local and the deployment artifact can be committed to a different branch for deployment, with all the dependencies.

Comment: Well, it’s one way. You can also write a shell script that mimics what BLT does and run that manually. I’ve dome it both ways.

Comment: To add to this, you could set up Jenkins internally too, or use the CI capabilities of GitLab to automate deployments either by BLT or manual script(s).